A time-travel short story where the using a time-travel device, its inventor provided an alibi for his future murderer (his wife)
I read this short story (or maybe just a novelette) 40 or 50 years ago, probably in a collection.
The most prominent character of this story (but not the POV character) is a brillant scientist, and a horrible husband.
He has single-handedly invented a time-travel device. Not exactly a time-machine à la H. G. Wells. What it does, if programmed to start acting at some point in the future, is to send a double of some original object in the past. The original object in unperturbed, and the double disappears at the instant when the device starts working. For inanimate objects, it is fine but the double sent in the past of living animals is always dead.
Instead of just showing his device to the world he wants to make it very dramatic, because he is extremely proud. And he is also a horrible husband. His plan is to send a double of himself to the past, have his wife show the dead double so it is well-known that he is dead. Together they arrange the dead double to make it appear it was an accident : he needs his wife to be free, not in prison accused of his murder, so she can check all goes exactly along his dramatic plan. Then he hides himself, expecting a huge reputation for his device when he "comes back from the dead". IIRC, he threatens to kill her if anything goes wrong and he does not receive as huge a success as he expects.
But then his wife kills him (the original one, in hiding) exactly in the way the (already dead) double had been arranged to appear. When the double disappears in due time, all she has to do is to put the husband she just killed where the double had been exposed.
Perfect crime !

Sounds so familiar.  Following this question....

This sounds like 'Obituary' by Isaac Asimov. The story is told from the POV of the wife who explains how her husband duplicated himself so he could fake his own death then reappear when the duplicate vanished. Except that she killed the real one and allowed the funeral to go ahead.
The story first appeared in the August 1959 issue of F&SF and was reprinted in Asimov's Mysteries. It can be read at the Luminist Archive here (google drive link to pdf).

That was a really good read... The main reason I like posts like this is because of how interesting some of these somewhat niche stories can be :D
